# Using C dll in delphi return nothing

Tags: delphi, dll, dllimport

I have been trying to reuse a C dll file in delphi based on this [documentation](http://maxdb.sap.com/documentation/sqldbc/SQLDBC_API/SQLDBC__C_8h.html#a252).

Server was running well, i could access and used the database on local server with 
java and php.

On delphi i used dynamic load and worked well on all functions that return variables but failed on those that return interface.

```
unit for library :
unit SQLDBC_C;

interface
uses windows, classes, sysutils;

type
  SQLDBC_IRuntime = interface
  end;

var
  getSDKVersion : function :Pchar; stdcall;
  ClientRuntime_GetClientRuntime: function (errorText:Pchar; errorTextSize:Integer) : SQLDBC_IRuntime; stdcall;

implementation

var
  libhandle : THandle;

procedure initLibrary;
begin
  libhandle := LoadLibrary('libSQLDBC_C.dll');
  if libhandle>=23 then begin
     @getSDKVersion:=GetProcAddress(libhandle,'getSDKVersion');
     @ClientRuntime_GetClientRuntime:=
        GetProcAddress(libhandle,'ClientRuntime_GetClientRuntime');
  end;
end;

initialization
begin
  initLibrary;
end;

finalization
begin
  if libhandle>=32 then
    FreeLibrary(libhandle);
end;

end.
```

here is the test procedure :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  err : array [0..200] of char;
  rt : SQLDBC_IRuntime;

begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  FillChar(err, sizeof(err), 0);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(getSDKVersion); //this function successed

  rt := ClientRuntime_GetClientRuntime(@err,200); 
  //this function had no return value, (rt always nil) but no error return at err variable
  if assigned(rt) then begin
    ......
  end;
end;
```

I've read the similar problems asked by [geskill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266417/delphi-calling-a-function-from-a-vc-dll-that-exports-a-interface-class), [Dan Hacker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629852/delphi-interface-from-dll), [max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846545/is-it-safe-to-use-interfaces-from-dll) and [Ron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798283/calling-dlls-with-pointers-in-delphi) but it could not solve my problem.

Could anyone told me what's wrong here?

Comment: Which version of Delphi? Are you sure it's stdcall? Quite plausible that it's cdecl.

Comment: This reminds me of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349530/why-can-a-widestring-not-be-used-as-a-function-return-value-for-interop

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for reply. There's no differences between stdcall and cdecl. I'm on Windows XP machine, trying Delphi 6, 7 and XE2.

Comment: Make sure you use AnsiChar for XE2. Best to use it always for this lib. Try a C++ program and check if that works. If so, what differs?

Comment: That's the problem. It works well on C++, java and php. On delphi 6, 7, and XE2, the library loaded sucessfully the functions that return String and numeric works well except all function that return Interface. If i use interface it returns nil.  If i use pointer, it returns pointer but throws exceptions.

Comment: Try using cdecl instead of stdcall

Comment: @chuckj Read the comments above. That was already suggested and tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot test it because I have no `libSQLDBC_C.dll`.

The problem was [already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349530/why-can-a-widestring-not-be-used-as-a-function-return-value-for-interop) . As a workaround for your case you can return a pointer in Delphi `ClientRuntime_GetClientRuntime` declaration

```
ClientRuntime_GetClientRuntime: function (errorText:Pchar;
                                errorTextSize:Integer): Pointer; stdcall;
```

and cast it to `SQLDBC_IRuntime` interface:

```
var
  err : array [0..200] of char;
  rt : SQLDBC_IRuntime;

begin
  Pointer(rt):= ClientRuntime_GetClientRuntime(@err,200);
```

Comment: I've done some trials and agree with what you write here (see my update). Sadly however, the `Pointer` trick is of no use in this instance.

Comment: Sure typecasting expects a COM interface (IUnknown descendant); but I suppose only a newbie can export a pointer to C++ class from dll, very strange to see it in a SAP product.

Comment: It's the same mistake as exporting a Delphi class from a DLL.

Comment: @serg : excellent idea of using pointer.  In my case, don't try to cast pointer to interface or you will get an exception. Leave the pointer as it is. Thanks.

Comment: But if you leave it as a pointer, how can you call methods on it?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. In this case, libSQLDBC_C.dll is a kind of C wrap. The original C++ library is libSQLDBC.dll.  Methods on all interface has been wrapped outside the interface. For example, on original C++ we should use SQLDBC_Environment->createConnection as the "createConnection" is a method of SQLDBC_Environment class. On libSQLDBC_C.dll we use "SQLDBC_Environment_createConnection" with SQLDBC_Environment as input param.

Comment: OK, so that's the bridge part of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A C++ function that returns an interface does not easily map to a Delphi function. The calling convention for return values that are managed types in Delphi does not match that used by C++.

To illustrate, I created a simple C++ test DLL that exports this function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) IUnknown* __stdcall GetInterface()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IUnknown* result;
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ActiveDesktop, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
      IID_IUnknown, (void**) &result);
    return result;
}
```

The obvious way to map this to Delphi is like this:

```
function GetInterface: IUnknown; stdcall; external DLL name '_GetInterface@0';
```

However, when we call this function it always returns `nil`.

The workaround is exactly as suggested by Serg:

```
function GetInterface: Pointer; stdcall; external DLL name '_GetInterface@0';
```

and we can then call it like this:

```
var
  intf: IUnknown;
....
Pointer(intf) := GetInterface;
```

When we do this, `intf` is not `nil` and we can call methods on it quite happily.

So, what we have learnt here is that Delphi cannot easily call external functions that return interfaces, unless those external functions were also implemented in Delphi. But at least we have a viable workaround.

---

Unfortunately this workaround is of no immediate use to you. That's because  `SQLDBC_IRuntime` is a C++ class. It is not a COM compatible interface. Note that `SQLDBC_IRuntime` does not implement `IInterface`. So it doesn't provide `_AddRef`, `_Release` and `QueryInterface`. Delphi's interface support is predicated on the availability of `IInterface`. And this means that that you cannot use `SQLDBC_IRuntime` from Delphi.

You will need to make a C++ bridge DLL that exposes the functionality in a way that Delphi can invoke. For example by exposing plain old functions that call the C++ methods of `SQLDBC_IRuntime`.

Comment: it does not return nil; the Delphi prototype is wrong, so the return value does not appear as the function's result.

Comment: @Serg Could you elaborate? Your link to my question doesn't apply here I think. There are many Win32 API functions that return COM interfaces so. My instincts are that the issue is that `SQLDBC_IRuntime` is simply not a COM interface. Even if you could get hold of it, what could you do with it?

Comment: No, WinAPI functions usually return HResult (doubleword), not interfaces; I can elaborate but I need to analyze the argument stack of the function.

Comment: @Serg You could be right. Did you read this yet: http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/33100/

Comment: Good link, I thought exactly the same about the problem.

Comment: Finally i got the answer : using pointer and create a wrap class using base connection and dataset class.  @Serg and David : Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Indeed `SQLDBC_IRuntime` is a C++ class: http://maxdb.sap.com/documentation/sqldbc/SQLDBC_API/classSQLDBC__IRuntime.html